# How to call a function from another PHP view without load it?

Tags: php, html

How to call a function from another view in current PHP view? Can anyone help me on this?
I only want it to display part of the include view, not the whole thing.

Comment: You want to call something without loading it?

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: How would you know what code needs to run if you don't load it to see?

Comment: Please add details.  As presented, it makes no sense.  What's wrong with include or require (and the _once versions)?

Comment: Hold on, why do you have a function in a view anyways? Your functions should be separate for this very reason

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton That view is not written by me. I need to use it.

Comment: @Nic3500 I don't want to display the whole page.

Comment: @LaylaWang Is it not an option to just copy the function from the view and use it elsewhere in the project?

Comment: Ah ok, so there is a mix of functions and display code (a no-no in my book!).

Comment: @Nic3500 Yes, it's mixed. T_T

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton There are many sub functions. About 700 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible with output buffering.

If you have a file like this (we'll call it example2.php):

```
<?php

function example() {
    echo 'For example';
}
?>

Here's some text that you don't want to see.
```

You can include it in example.php in an output buffer. Clear the buffer without printing its contents, and you'll still have access to the function.

```
<?php

ob_start();

include 'example2.php';

ob_clean();

example();
```

Keep in mind that *all the PHP code* in example2.php will be executed, and there may be undesirable side effects.

Comment: If you read the comments, you will see that the problem is that function code is mixed with display code, so include and require are not options.

Comment: @Nic3500 I read the comments. This won't display anything from the included file. It just reads the display produced by include into an output buffer, then discards it without doing anything with it.

Comment: @Nic3500 no worries. I don't really think doing it this way is a good idea, but it's theoretically possible.

Comment: Thanks guys! I know this is not a perfect solution, but good enough.